# How do I print before asking for input every time?

Tags: ruby, stdin

I'm having a problem because I want to combine 2 ways I know of getting input from the user. I want to print "% " before the user can begin typing, but I also want to do this for every possible line of input.

Normally I would do

```
print "% "
input = gets.chomp
```

or

```
$stdin.each_line do |line|
   ...
end
```

but I'm not sure how to print before reading in each line of the loop. Is there a simple solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script asks you for input, until you type '42' <sup>([it is an earth simulator by the way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy))</sup> Something is printed before every input.

```
loop do
  print "Think of a question and give me its answer: "
  a = gets
  break if a.chomp == "42"
end
puts "You have found a possible question!"
```

Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: Something like this-- I ended up doing a begin end inside of a loop so I could catch an exception

Answer (score 0):

we can do

```
begin
  print "%: "
  a = gets
  puts a
end (condition)
```

or

```
input = "%" + gets.chomp
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an editor it may be managing the buffer.  This is a common problem.

You can set `STDOUT.sync = true` at the top of the file program and this may be your solution, or you can use `STDOUT.fluxh` directly before your gets statement.

Otherwise, run your programs from the terminal/console/shell rather than your IDE.